# HichCharts weird margin on pie chart because data labels

Tags: highcharts, margin, pie-chart

I'm trying to generate a pie chart but when I activate the data labels the chart's width is incorrectly calculated.

Is this a bug or I must to set other options ?

The example :

http://jsfiddle.net/rolivares/Fcca9/6/

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            animation: false,
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
```

PD: Toggle plotOptions.dataLabels.enabled = true/false

Comment: You need to increase size parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size

Comment: So simple that scares! thanks a lot!

Comment: This graph is embedded inside a responsive page. So, does it possible set a porcentual width. or something,  in order to allow the graph fit to his container automatically?

Comment: Yes you can set width in percent on the div styles.